# OpenCV cvFindContours - how do i find ellipse contour in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, javacv, ellipse

I use Javacv to find images of rice grains in a picture.

[image]

I have implemented this code:

```
String fileName = "image/rice.jpg";
IplImage image = cvLoadImage(fileName);
IplImage _image = cvCloneImage(image);

image = Guassian.apply(image, 3);
image = Grayscale.apply(image);
image = Threshold.apply(image, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
image = MORPH.apply(image, 7, 3, CV_MOP_ERODE);
image = MORPH.apply(image, 7, 3, CV_MOP_DILATE);
image = Canny.apply(image);

CvSeq cvSeq = new CvSeq();
CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

cvFindContours(image, storage, cvSeq, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (int i = 0; i < cvSeq.total(); i++) {
    cvEllipse(cvSeq, CvPoint.ZERO, CvSize.ZERO, i, dp, dp, CvScalar.ONE, i, i, i);
}
```

In the line `cvEllipse(cvSeq, CvPoint.ZERO, CvSize.ZERO, i, dp, dp, CvScalar.ONE, i, i, i);`, how can I set a parameter?

Comment: Which parameter are you trying to set?

Comment: @David Gorsline you can show me a simple code and explain

Comment: [ellipse](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse)  so, at least the 3rd param , CvSize.ZERO for the (x,y)axis length seems wrong, will give you an invisible one

Comment: also, you forgot to specify, what exactly went wong with your approach

Comment: i try to set a parameter but i'm encounter an error , cvEllipse() don't work , give me for example